# how do i my sef link use .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

My link is "**site.com/index.php?w=Mbv**"

I want see: "**site.com/Mbv**"

I try the *mod_rewrite RewriteRule Generator* and more beacuse its not working no one.

*sorry for my bad english.*

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in .htaccess write this

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-])$ /index.php?w=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks. i try it. because error 404 bla bla bla...